# Publishing a Bibliography on a Blog

Tags: citations, copyright, online-publication

I plan to start a blog on using free technology in the classroom, but I want to have a strong scholarly element to my posts. I would like to keep a site-wide bibliography on the blog that summarizes the articles that I am referencing. For each article, I plan on having a full summary of its methods and conclusions in the bibliography. Is it alright to do this (legally-speaking) as long as I properly cite each source?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that your "bibliography" will consist of a collection of paper reviews?

Answer (score 1):

Bibliographies are mainly public (e.g., looking for Bibtex of an article). So, here are my suggestion for how to use citations in a blog:

**Citations**: You could use either a repository solution and put all the citations on a third party website/server(s), or just use a Json or XML to sort the citations and add the citations, as a URL, at the end of your blog posts.